# How to use GPG keys with Yubikey in WSL2 to authenticate GIT?

Tags: gnupg, wsl-2, yubikey, gpg-agent

I am trying to setup Yubikey in `WSL2` (Ubuntu distro) to use GPG key as SSH keys to authenticate to GIT server. Below is my setup

```
YubiKey Manager (ykman) version: 5.1.1
How was it installed?: Using Yubico's PPA (Ubuntu)
Operating system and version: WSL2; 1.2.5.0; Windows version: 10.0.22621.819 (Ubuntu distro)
YubiKey model and version: YubiKey 5 NFC (5.4.3)
```

I am following the guide [accessing Yubikey in WSL2](https://dev.to/dzerycz/the-ultimate-guide-to-yubikey-on-wsl2-part-2-kli) and to connect WSL’s ssh agent to GPG key over socket, I have installed `socat` and `wsl2-ssh-pageant` in WSL. Also, added below section `~/.bashrc` to sync sockets

```
config_path="C\:/Users/<YOUR_USER>/AppData/Local/gnupg"
wsl2_ssh_pageant_bin="$HOME/.ssh/wsl2-ssh-pageant.exe"
# SSH Socket
# Removing Linux SSH socket and replacing it by link to wsl2-ssh-pageant socket
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$HOME/.ssh/agent.sock"
if ! ss -a | grep -q "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"; then
  rm -f "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
  if test -x "$wsl2_ssh_pageant_bin"; then
    (setsid nohup socat UNIX-LISTEN:"$SSH_AUTH_SOCK,fork" EXEC:"$wsl2_ssh_pageant_bin" >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
  else
    echo >&2 "WARNING: $wsl2_ssh_pageant_bin is not executable."
  fi
fi
# GPG Socket
# Removing Linux GPG Agent socket and replacing it by link to wsl2-ssh-pageant GPG socket
export GPG_AGENT_SOCK="$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent"
if ! ss -a | grep -q "$GPG_AGENT_SOCK"; then
  rm -rf "$GPG_AGENT_SOCK"
  if test -x "$wsl2_ssh_pageant_bin"; then
    (setsid nohup socat UNIX-LISTEN:"$GPG_AGENT_SOCK,fork" EXEC:"$wsl2_ssh_pageant_bin --gpgConfigBasepath ${config_path} --gpg S.gpg-agent" >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
  else
    echo >&2 "WARNING: $wsl2_ssh_pageant_bin is not executable."
  fi
fi
```

And now `gpg --card-status` shows the Yubikey info and also configured GPG keys using `gpg --card-edit`.
But, to get SSH public key using `ssh-add -L` I am getting `error fetching identities: communication with agent failed` error.

`gpg-agent` is running

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it?

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing

Answer (score 0):

Add YubiKey as a device to WSL2. Follow this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb